# Batch Script Cant get If statements working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, statements

My batch script was working fine until I tried to add some long if statements.
Im new to this and would like if someone could check whats wrong. Im trying to do a pricing calculator based on what rank you are.

Heres the section of it that isn't working.

```
if "%drating%" < "1500" (set /a price=%price%+3)
else if "%drating%" < "2000" (@set /a price=%price%+5)
else if "%drating%" < "2500" (@set /a price=%price%+6)
else if "%drating%" < "2700" (@set /a price=%price%+8)
else if "%drating%" < "3000" (@set /a price=%price%+10)
else if "%drating%" < "3300" (@set /a price=%price%+12)
else if "%drating%" < "3500" (@set /a price=%price%+14)
else if "%drating%" < "3800" (@set /a price=%price%+20)
else if "%drating%" < "3900" (@set /a price=%price%+30)
else if "%drating%" < "4000" (@set /a price=%price%+40)
else if "%drating%" < "4100" (@set /a price=%price%+50)
else (
echo There is no available price for %drating%.
echo Press any key to exit.
set /p exitkey=
)
```

heres what i did after magoo

```
if "%drating%" LSS "1500" (set /a price=%price%+3
) else (if "%drating%" LSS "2000" (set /a price=%price%+5
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "2500" (set /a price=%price%+6
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "2700" (set /a price=%price%+8
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "3000" (set /a price=%price%+10
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "3300" (set /a price=%price%+12
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "3500" (set /a price=%price%+14
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "3800" (set /a price=%price%+20
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "3900" (set /a price=%price%+30
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "4000" (set /a price=%price%+40
 ) else (if "%drating%" LSS "4100" (set /a price=%price%+50
 ) else (echo There is no available price for %drating%.
echo Press any key to exit.
set /p exitkey=
exit
)
```

Comment: Helps if you read the help for the command you are trying to use.  Open up a command prompt and type: `if /?`

Comment: i have read it, no idea what i done wrong though

Comment: Really!!!! You see the less than symbol in the help file.

Comment: And you should definitely be reading the section that starts with: **The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.  For example:**

Comment: well im an idiot ok, thanks for that. I though it said you could use > < aswell. Now that im using LSS, its giving me error with Else. Im super confused now.

Comment: I read that, but Im not sure what it really means, since I didnt understand the example.

Comment: I added the else statement on the same line, and it works. But theres like a quick bunch of errors along with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if %drating% lss 1500 (set /a price=%price%+3
) else (if %drating% lss 2000 (set /a price=%price%+5
 ) else (
 )
)
```

the `lss` operator means "less". You need to omit the quotes so that a *numeric* comparison is performed, with quotes performs a literal comparison.

The `else` clause **must** be preceded and succeeded by the appropritae parentheses, as shown on the same physical line.

All parenthesis pairs must be completed.

If you have executed a `@echo off` statement, `echo`ing of the commands will be suppressed. It's normal to place this statement at the beginning of a batch. Further `@statement`s are not required - the `@` simply suppresses the echo of the resolved following statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your code and just do it like this.

```
@echo off
set "price=10"
set "drating=4099"
if %drating% lss 1500 (set /a "price+=3" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 2000 (set /a "price+=5" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 2500 (set /a "price+=6" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 2700 (set /a "price+=8" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 3000 (set /a "price+=10" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 3300 (set /a "price+=12" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 3500 (set /a "price+=14" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 3800 (set /a "price+=20" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 3900 (set /a "price+=30" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 4000 (set /a "price+=40" &GOTO SKIP)
if %drating% lss 4100 (set /a "price+=50" &GOTO SKIP)

echo There is no available price for %drating%.
pause
GOTO :EOF

:SKIP
echo drating=%drating% price=%price%

pause
```